# STM32 timer with DWT problem

Tags: stm32, timer

I'm using STM32F103.I'm trying to make a code that run every second.
here is the code

```
//Clock is 32Mhz
unsigned long usStart,usStop;
CoreDebug->DEMCR |= CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk;
DWT->CYCCNT = 0;
DWT-> CTRL |= DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk;
usStop = DWT->CYCCNT / 32000;
While(1){
usStart = DWT->CYCCNT / 32000;
if(abs(usStart - usStop) >= 1000){
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13);
    usStop = DWT->CYCCNT / 32000;
   }
}
```

After aproximatly 20second the code crash and stop working.
I couldn't figure out why this happens.I thought that was because of the CYCCNT overflows so I added abs() in the diffrence calculation but still the same problem.

Comment: You have not given a lot of information here. Is the CPU clock 32 MHz? What are the variable types for usStop and usStart? My best guess is you are using 16-bit integers, worse if signed, so because of the division by 32000 does not wrap around cleanly you latch a CYCCNT value so high that is difficult to exceed.

Comment: Yes the clock is 32Mhz and the variables are unsigned long I forgot to add those informations.So what is the solution if CYCCNT is latched as you said ? what is the correct way to make a timed code (I need it to be in Microseconds since I will use it as both microseconds and milliseconds)